# Export/Import entities which were created server-side

Tags: breeze

If you create entity client-side through EntityManager.createEntity(), when exporting, breeze generates tempKeys and assigns them to newly created entities.

But some entities are created server-side, but not saved(just created with new operator). Breezejs client is making a query. EntityState of fetched entities is Unchanged. PrimaryKey Id=0, it was just created, but not saved to db.
When you make exportEntities on manager it does not generate tempKeys, and entity Id remains zero. I tried to manually set EntityState to Added on that entities before exporting, but still tempKeys are not generated.

Any ideas how to properly export not-saved entity which came from server-side?

Answer (score 0):

I think Breeze only creates a new temp key when the entity is *attached* to the EntityManager with state 'Added'.  So try this:

```
entityManager.detachEntity(entity);
entityManager.attachEntity(entity, breeze.EntityState.Added);
```

That should cause a new temp key to be generated.